# How do I get the value of a property corresponding to a SQLAlchemy InstrumentedAttribute?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org) mapped class `Table` and an instance of that class `t`, how do I get the value of `t.colname` corresponding to the `sqlalchemy.org.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute` instance `Table.colname`?

What if I need to ask the same question with a `Column` instead of an `InstrumentedAttribute`?

Given a list of columns in an `ORDER BY` clause and a row, I would like to find the first n rows that come before or after that row in the given ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get an objects attribute value corresponding to an `InstrumentedAttribute` it should be enough to just get the key of the attribute from it's `ColumnProperty` and fetch it from the object:

```
t.colname == getattr(t, Table.colname.property.key)
```

If you have a `Column` it can get a bit more complicated because the property that corresponds to the `Column` might have a different key. There currently doesn't seem to be a public API to get from a column to the corresponding property on a mapper. But if you don't need to cover all cases, just fetch the attr using `Column.key`.

To support descending orderings you'll either need to construct the `desc()` inside the function or poke a bit at non-public API's. The class of the descending modifier `ClauseElement` is `sqlalchemy.sql.expression._UnaryExpression`. To see if it is descending you'll need to check if the `.modifier` attribute is `sqlalchemy.sql.operators.desc_op`. If that case you can get at the column inside it via the `.element` attribute. But as you can see it is a private class, so watch for any changes in that area when upgrading versions.

Checking for descending still doesn't cover all the cases. Fully general support for arbitrary orderings needs to be able to rewrite full SQL expression trees replacing references to a table with corresponding values from an object. Unfortunately this isn't  possible with public API's at this moment. The traversal and rewriting part is easy with `sqlalchemy.sql.visitors.ReplacingCloningVisitor`, the complex part is figuring out which column maps to which attribute given inheritance hierarchies, mappings to joins, aliases and probably some more parts that escape me for now. I'll give a shot at implementing this visitor, maybe I can come up with something robust enough to be worthy of integrating into SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Did this happen? Given a `Column` and a class or instance, I'd like to discover the `InstrumentedAttribute` it's associated with.

Answer (score 0):

here an example, even if you are using field names different from those defined in table

#### sample model

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dest = Column(String,nullable=False)
    state = Column(Integer)
    meta = Column("metadata",JSONB)
```

#### how inspect

```
class_attributes = vars(MyModel)

# Iterate over the attributes and check if they are columns
for attr_name, attr_value in class_attributes.items():
    if isinstance(attr_value, InstrumentedAttribute):
        table_column_name = attr_value.expression.key
        model_column_name = attr_value.key
        print(f"{model_column_name} is a column with database name: {table_column_name}.")
```

#### expected output

```
id is a column with database name: id. 
dest is a column with database name: dest. 
state is a column with database name: state. 
meta is a column with database name: metadata.
```